# Post comments: 'Twitter handles' not working at beginning of mini-Markdown

Tags: support

When I begin a comment with `@name` the handle disappears.

Only inserting it somewhere in the middle saves it from disappearing when I click on
the Add Comment button.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does that happen for any name but the post owners? Also, this is a [meta-tag:support] question, not [meta-tag:feature-request] (And I doubt you uncovered a [meta-tag:bug]).

Comment: This is dup, but a tough to search for one... here's the MSE FAQ on how `@`-replies work: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the link. I found the answer to my question here:

> The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of
>   any new comment. There is no need to use @name to notify them. (You
>   may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the
>   author have been commenting on the post so far, the @name will be
>   automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no
>   value.)

Comment: Is this a new feature?

Comment: @Scimonster no, always been like this